# I need to copy a string from one MainActivity to WebActivity / Opening scanned QR result in Webview

Tags: android, class, qr-code, getter, zbar

So, I have 2 java classes. These are my MainActivity.java and WebActivity.java (below). What I want to to: I want to copy the string scannedurl (which I created to contain the scanned QR code) from MainActivity to WebActivity, so that it can be used as a URL somehow. I've given more details after showing both classes.

```
package com.example.myqrscanner;

import android.app.Activity;...

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private Handler autoFocusHandler;
    private Button button;

    TextView scanText;
    Button scanButton;
    String scannedurl;

    ImageScanner scanner;

    private boolean barcodeScanned = false;
    private boolean previewing = true;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("iconv");
    } 

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = this;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);        }});



        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        autoFocusHandler = new Handler();
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        // Instance barcode scanner
        scanner = new ImageScanner();
        scanner.setConfig(0, Config.X_DENSITY, 3);
        scanner.setConfig(0, Config.Y_DENSITY, 3);

        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera, previewCb, autoFocusCB);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);

        scanText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scanText);

        scanButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ScanButton);

        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (barcodeScanned) {
                        barcodeScanned = false;
                        scanText.setText("Scanare...");
                        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCb);
                        mCamera.startPreview();
                        previewing = true;
                        mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseCamera();
    }

    /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e){
        }
        return c;
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            previewing = false;
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    private Runnable doAutoFocus = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (previewing)
                    mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
            }
        };

    PreviewCallback previewCb = new PreviewCallback() {
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();

                Image barcode = new Image(size.width, size.height, "Y800");
                barcode.setData(data);

                int result = scanner.scanImage(barcode);

                if (result != 0) {
                    previewing = false;
                    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
                    mCamera.stopPreview();



SymbolSet syms = scanner.getResults();
                    for (Symbol sym : syms) {
                        scanText.setText("Cod QR identificat: " + sym.getData());
                        barcodeScanned = true;
                        scannedurl = sym.getData();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        public String getscannedurl()
        { return scannedurl; }


    // Simulate continuous auto-focusing by sending a focus request every 1000 ms
    AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCB = new AutoFocusCallback() {
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                autoFocusHandler.postDelayed(doAutoFocus, 1000);
            }
        };
}
```

WebActivity is below:

```
package com.example.myqrscanner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webcontent);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("Here I want to add the string scannedurl from MainActivty");

    }

}
```

So I need to import that string here (webView.loadUrl(???)) after it was read by the QR scanner. 
I tried the getter and setter method and a few other alternatives but I got lost on the way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the intent in your main activity

MainActivity.java

```
 String status="Scanned URL";

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("USERNAME",status);
                    startActivity(intent);        
          }
         });
```

WebActivity.java

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String receivedName = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra("USERNAME");
webView.loadUrl(receivedName);
```

Comment: This did the trick. I also had to make another minor change to MainActivity but it worked great. Thanks a lot.